# Input buttons value to v-model on click

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

So I got this buttons and an input.
Whenever I click one of each button, I want the arrow to appear in the answer field, for example If i click twice left arrow and twice right arrow, I want 4 of them to be in my input. How can I achieve this?

[image]

```html
<button class="arrow_button">←</button>
<button class="arrow_button">↑</button>
<button class="arrow_button">↓</button>
<button class="arrow_button">→</button>

<input v-model="passwordAnswer" placeholder="Password" />
```

Comment: concatenate the value on the model `@click="passwordAnswer += '←'"` (add to each of your buttons)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a click handler to all of your buttons, like this:

```
<button class="arrow_button" @click="passwordAnswer += '←'">←</button>
<button class="arrow_button" @click="passwordAnswer += '↑'">↑</button>
<button class="arrow_button" @click="passwordAnswer += '↓'">↓</button>
<button class="arrow_button" @click="passwordAnswer += '→'">→</button>

<input v-model="passwordAnswer" placeholder="Password" />
```

To avoid duplicates you can use `v-for` and iterate over an array of your options (arrows) to create the buttons.